# ROS_INFO_STREAM

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does ROS_INFO_STREAM, ROS_INFO, and ROS_ERROR do? Do they output data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10823/ros_info_stream/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [rosconsole docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole) for details on these logging macros. You can view and configure the verbosity for a particular node using [rxconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-04**:
Thanks. For some reason I couldn't find anything about them through google or the ROS search.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-20**:
(!) rx packages are replaced by [rqt](https://wiki.ros.org/rqt), which is available for fuerte and later.

rqt_console is a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know if the information has been moved since this question was answered but the given link to rosconsole docs mentions nothing about ROS_INFO and the top search result on google takes you to this page :-( I was able to discern from the description in Learning ROS for Robotics Programming that the difference between ROS_INFO and ROS_INFO_STREAM is that the former is intended for C and the latter for C++. However it seems a bit more complicated than that. I had several ROS_INFO calls in my C++ code that seemed to work fine but in another place ROS_INFO_STREAM worked while ROS_INFO printed nothing. ROS_ERROR is for sending error messages to whatever stream or fd you have set up for errors

---

Originally posted by [sunking](https://answers.ros.org/users/27241/sunking/) with karma: 31 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-24**:
the [rosconsole docs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole) linked by @Eric Perko list all the logging macros in the [Code API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Code_API) section. The examples are just given once, but at the end of the section the other *verbosity levels* are listed. That includes `INFO`.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-05-10**:
I agree, and it would seem more clear to give explicit examples, or even something like `ROS_VERBOSITY_TYPE` as a base format so it's clear that every time we see `ROS_DEBUG_X`, the `DEBUG` could be otherwise. As is, the user has to infer this (and beginners likely won't, hence this question).

**Comment by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) on 2019-11-10**:
@gvdhoom There is no match for `ROS_INFO` on that page.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-11-12**:
@pauljurczak The previous comment exactly says why `ROS_INFO` can't be found on the page :

> every time we see ROS_DEBUG_X, the DEBUG could be otherwise

**Comment by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) on 2019-11-12**:
@Delb It took me a while to understand what you meant. It is certainly beyond any search engine capability. I'm going to edit ROS Wiki to make it more clear to newbies like me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:
+1 to clarifying, but please do not add copies of everything for every vebosity type.

**Comment by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) on 2019-11-13**:
@gvdhoom That would be too much typing ;-)  I just edited that page - have a look.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:
I've added some edits myself ([diff](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole/CodeAPI?action=diff&rev1=8&rev2=9)). +1 for making the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ROS_INFO` macro accepts C-style `printf` formatting parameters as in this example from "Mastering ROS'":

```
ROS_INFO("From Client [%s], Server says [%s]", req.in.c_str(), res.out.c_str())
```

`ROS_INFO_STREAM` macro accepts C++ style `std::iostream` formatting as in this example from "A Gentle Introduction to ROS":

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command: " << " linear=" << msg. linear . x << "angular=" << msg. angular . z)
```

---

Originally posted by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) with karma: 85 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7